# How to access object key values semantically

Tags: javascript

```
const COMPUTE_CODES = Object.freeze({
  'D+1': '0011111',
  'A+1': '0110111',
  'D-1': '0001110',
  'A-1': '0110010',
  'D+A': '0000010',
  'D-A': '0010011',
  'A-D': '0000111'
  // more 
})
```

I want to get the value if key is either `D+1` or `1+D`, but since there are many keys, I don't want to add more redundant semantic keys.

I tried to sort the given key, `'1+D'.split('').sort().join('').toUpperCase() // +1D`  but it is `+1D` not `D+1`.

The question is to access all keys, not `D+1`, it is a specific example.

```
const COMPUTE_CODES = Object.freeze({
      'D+1': '0011111',
      '1+D': '0011111',
      'A+1': '0110111',
      '1+A': '0110111',
      'D-1': '0001110',
      '1-D': '0001110',
      'A-1': '0110010',
      '1-A': '0110010',
      // more 
    })
```

I don't want to write like this.

Comment: I want to get value `0011111` when key is either `D+1` or `1+D`.

Comment: Please show us an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried

Comment: Write a function that canonicalizes the key, so `1+D` is converted to `D+1`. Then use `COMPUTE_CODES[canonical_key(key))`

Comment: You could add an access function to the object that validates the key before returning, .get(key) { if ( typeof key == "string"  && typeof this[key] == "string" ) { return this[key]; } }

Comment: `Object.keys(COMPUTE_CODES).filter(key => ["D+1","1+D"].includes(key))`

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it's just that one pair, I think he wants this to work for any blah1+blah2.

Comment: from the description that is all I got

Comment: What did you get from "since I there are many keys I don't want to add more redundant semantic keys." That seems to be talking about a more general problem.

Comment: Are the keys always <letter><+/-><digit>? Or what is the general pattern here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and use a reversed key, if necessary.

```js
const
    COMPUTE_CODES = { 'D+1': '0011111', 'A+1': '0110111', 'D-1': '0001110', 'A-1': '0110010', 'D+A': '0000010', 'D-A': '0010011', 'A-D': '0000111' },
    codes = new Proxy(COMPUTE_CODES, {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
            return prop in target
                ? target[prop]
                : target[prop.split(/([+-])/).reverse().join('')];
        }
    });
    

console.log(codes['1+D']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the key that's given. If it doesn't exist, flip it around the `+` or `-` character and try that.

```
function get_compute_code(key) {
    if (key in COMPUTE_CODES) {
        return COMPUTE_CODES[key];
    }
    // try flipping the key around
    key = key.replace(/^(.*)([-+])(.*)/, '$3$2$1')
    return COMPUTE_CODES[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply check straight and reverse

```js
function getCode(code){
 return COMPUTE_CODES[code] || COMPUTE_CODES[code.split('').reverse().join('')]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [a `Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for that

```js
const semanticGetterForProps = {
  get: (obj, name) => obj[name] || obj[[...name].reverse().join("")]
};
const COMPUTE_CODES =  new Proxy({
  'D+1': '0011111',
  'A+1': '0110111',
  'D-1': '0001110',
  'A-1': '0110010',
  'D+A': '0000010',
  'D-A': '0010011',
  'A-D': '0000111',
}, semanticGetterForProps);

console.log(COMPUTE_CODES["1+D"]);
console.log(COMPUTE_CODES["D+1"]);
console.log(COMPUTE_CODES["1-A"]);
console.log(COMPUTE_CODES["A-1"]);
console.log(COMPUTE_CODES["A+1"]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const COMPUTE_CODES = Object.freeze({
  'D+1': '0011111',
  'A+1': '0110111',
  'D-1': '0001110',
  'A-1': '0110010',
  'D+A': '0000010',
  'D-A': '0010011',
  'A-D': '0000111'
  // more 
})

function get(key) {
  return COMPUTE_CODES[key] || COMPUTE_CODES[reverseKey(key)]
}

function reverseKey(key) {
  const separator = key.charAt(1)
  const [first, second] = key.split(separator)
  return `${second}${separator}${first}`
}

console.log(get('1+D'))
```

Comment: The `reverseKey` function seems like an overkill by using `.split`. You can simply do `const [first, separator, second] = key;` and skip the splitting and finding the separator.